# Проблема с animate в JQ

Tags: jquery, анимация, opacity, javascript

Проблема в том что если нажать "Закрепить" и убрать курсор с элемента "div.a" пока setTimeout* не истек то он пропадает в небытье

- setTimeout - это имитация post запроса который выполняется некоторое время, из-за этого ошибка

http://jsfiddle.net/LDJd7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.a').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).children('.b').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 200);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('approve')) {
    $(this).children('.b').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.0
        }, 150);}

}).on('click', function() {
    var t = this;
    $(this).addClass('approve');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(t).children('.b').hide().html('<a href="javascript:\\">Закреплено</a>').fadeIn(150).attr('class', 'no');
    }, 500);

});​
```

Попробуйте что-то около такого. Вообщем поиграйтесь с флагами.